# How to log an unhandled exception outside the main thead in WCF?

Tags: multithreading, wcf, error-handling

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS. The service already has a class implementing IErrorHandler where I log exceptions thrown in the context of a service call. The problem is, when the service is called it spawns a new thread to perform additional processing. When testing I discovered that any exception thrown in this thread will not get caught by my error handler. So, what alternative do I have to log this exception? Is there any way to plug AppDomain.UnhandledException somewhere? I have no problem with the IIS process being killed, I just don't want the error to go unnoticed.

### UPDATE:

For the moment, what I've done is plug the AppDomain.UnhandledException event in a shared constructor in the service class. It seems to work, but I'm not sure if it's the better way to do it.

Comment: does the launched thread job complete with in the context of main call ? or is it like a background job that keeps running even after response is sent ?

Comment: @np-hard: It is a background thread.

Comment: i think your best option is to put error handing code in your background job, i had a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896182/hosting-clr-and-catching-threading-exceptions)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are at the mercy of the hosting environment for this situation.  As @np-hard says you will need to handle the errors in your background job somehow.

You can be a little bit fancy about it - [this](http://flimflan.com/blog/SafelyRunningBackgroundThreadsInASPNET20.aspx) is a good article about how to handle exceptions raised in background threads and move them into the foreground so they can be handled by the standard Application_Error handler.  You could do that or just handle them directly and don't forward them on.